# How to print a data field in two different columns in FastReports

Tags: delphi, oracle11g, delphi-7, fastreport

So, I have a table in database like this :

```
number varchar2 (50)
activities varchar2 (50)
value number
flag varchar(2)
```

for `flag`, I have 2 options which means :
1=debit and 2=credit.
assume I wanted to create a report using fastreport 4, I'll make the report look like this :

[image]

my question is, how do you code in fastreport so that every value with flag 1 will show up in debit column and value with flag 2 shows up in credit column?
I am using delphi 7 by the way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use band's `OnBeforePrint` event:

```
procedure MasterData1OnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);
begin
   if <reportdataset."FLAG"> = '1' then begin
      MemoDebit.Text  := FormatFloat('#0.00', <reportdataset."VALUE">);
      MemoCredit.Text := FormatFloat('#0.00', 0);                                           
      end
   else if <reportdataset."FLAG"> = '2' then begin
      MemoDebit.Text  := FormatFloat('#0.00', 0);                                           
      MemoCredit.Text := FormatFloat('#0.00', <reportdataset."VALUE">);
      end
   else begin
      MemoDebit.Text  := FormatFloat('#0.00', 0);                                           
      MemoCredit.Text := FormatFloat('#0.00', 0);
   end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

FastReport can include an IIF statement in a TfrxMemoView.

Your report band will include two fields, one for the Debit column and one for the credit column.

Then in the debits field, you will enter:

```
[IIF(<Data."flag"> = '1', <Data."value">, '')]
```

And in the credits field:

```
[IIF(<Data."flag"> = '2', <Data."value">, '')]
```

The IIF statement can also be used inside a Sum() call in footers to get the correct totals.

```
[SUM(IIF(<Data."flag"> = '1', <Data."value">, 0))]
```

Comment: hi @mark-elder , the iif code raised error : "; expected"

Comment: @mizkyd kind of hard to guess without seeing what you input. Fast Reports has lots of brackets in different places. I was missing a paren in my "sum" example, I just fixed that.

Comment: @mizkyd what do you have under the Code tab? The error seems like it is coming from code. The values I put above are the actual text value for the fields. No code/script is needed.

Comment: ok that works. however my debet/kredit values are in currency so I need to convert it float type and make it show thousand separator and ,00 after the values. however, I wanted to make it show '-' if it's null. I tried make that tfrxmemoview to float formatting however it returns error cause - is not float value. any idea how to make this happens?

Comment: You can replace the empty string values ('') with either a 0 (with no quotes), or a <null>. Not sure how you are doing the formatting but I have run into the same issue where Fast Report tries to format an empty string differently than a null or zero.